# Issues with post_logout_redirect_uri in Keycloak and Grafana Integration

Tags: oauth, keycloak, grafana

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am currently facing a challenge with integrating Keycloak and Grafana, specifically regarding the post_logout_redirect_uri functionality. Despite setting up everything as per the documentation, the redirect after logout isn't functioning as expected.

#### Environment:

- Keycloak version: 19.0.3
- Grafana version: 10.2.3

#### Issue Description:

I've configured Keycloak's post_logout_redirect_uri to redirect to https://localhost:3000/login (encoded as https%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.27%3A3000%2Flogin). However, instead of redirecting to the specified Grafana login page after logging out from Keycloak, it redirects to https://localhost:3000/logout

#### Steps Taken:

Checked and confirmed the Valid Redirect URIs and Web Origins in Keycloak. Verified the signout_redirect_url configuration in Grafana. Ensured the URL is correctly encoded. Despite these checks and configurations, the redirection post-logout is not happening as intended.

#### Question:

1. Has anyone experienced a similar issue with the post_logout_redirect_uri in Keycloak when integrated with Grafana?
2. Are there known issues or workarounds that specifically address this problem?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue fixed in v10.3 release

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/79271

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md